# Is this a memory leak? Over 400.000 unreachable instances of org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.StoredRecordHeader

Tags: java, memory-leaks, derby

I had my application running over the weekend and on monday I was greeted by a `Java heap space` exception.

I analyzed the heap dump and noticed that there where over 400.000 instances of `org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.StoredRecordHeader` marked as unreachable objects.

Does anyone know if this could explain the memory error?

**Edit:**

After analyizing for half of the day I am not sure that the

> StoredRecordHeader

instances are responsible for the  **Java heap exception** but I have no clue why this is happening.

Are there some kind of caching mechanism in Derby that I'm unaware of?

Are 512MB max RAM to less for Derby to work stable?

Can I somehow modify the max size of the derby cache?

Comment: How are you using Derby? In memory database?

Comment: No, the DB is in the file system. I'm NOT using 'jdbc:derby:memory:myDB;create=true'.                    Im using: jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/D:\rcpapplication.product\database.

Comment: I think eclipse memory analyzer tool might have a wizard to help you look at long-lived object http://eclipse.org/mat/

Comment: You can configure the size of the Derby caches, but you shouldn't have to. I generally only configure the overall size of the JVM, not the individual Derby cache sizes.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a fix for this?  I'm seeing something similar where I was getting an error and I can see lots of instances of the StoredRecordHeader class.  Error says "GC overhead limit exceeded: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unreachable instances should be removed by Garbage Collector and are certainly not a reason for OutOfMemoryError. This error happens when your application has too many objects, that are *reachable* from GC roots and thus GC cannot throw them away. More information can be found here: [Plumbr encyclopaedia](https://plumbr.eu/outofmemoryerror/java-heap-space).

In order to find root cause for memory leak or any memory exhaustion situation, it is usually much easier to use some specialised tool, such as [Plumbr](http://plumbr.eu) or [Eclipse memory analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/).